# POST request to php mysql using python's requests

Tags: php, python

I am sending a bunch of sensor readings from my raspberrypi to a hosted php+mysql database using 3g network. 
I wrote the following code:

```
import requests
payload = {'reading1': 'xxxxxxx', 'reading2': 'xxxxxxx'}
r = requests.post("http://x.x.net/x.php", params=payload)
print r.status_code
```

My readings can be very frequent (around 1 reading per second). My question is, is this a good practice to write this post request? or should I store my readings in a variable and make the post request every 5 minutes. If the latter is better, how can I do it?

Comment: Only call it when you need it. If you need it to be updated every second, then you're going to have to deal with massive bandwidth issues.

Comment: 'Good Practice' is opting to use a specific approach knowing the consequences. As @NicholasPickering says, posts every second will cause an increase in bandwidth requirements. If you don't need to post every second, 'good practice' might be to hold out as long as you can, to reduce the impact of your script. That said, frequent posts may not have any noticeable impact on your system at all, so I'm sure it would be fine in that case too.

Comment: Great, so how do you recommend I store the data? should it be stored in a local database or textfile and then uploaded every 5 minutes to server which appends it to the database? Is there a way I can send an array of readings to the database rather than a single value per reading?