# Scheduling periodic uploads, good practice?

Tags: python

I am sending a bunch of sensor readings from my raspberrypi to a hosted php+mysql database using 3g network.

To save bandwidth and energy, it [was recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050761/post-request-to-php-mysql-using-pythons-requests) that rather than uploading sensor readings every second,  I should only upload periodically i.e. say every 5 minutes. So i decided to collect the readings using JSON format to ease up the uploading POST process:

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
```

I also set a timer using the timer2 module:

```
>>> timer2.apply_interval(msecs, fun, args, kwargs, priority=0)
```

Now fun is called every 5*3600*1000. In fun, I upload the payload and reset the payload content for next round of data collection :

```
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

---

The question:

- Is it good practice to reset the contents of the variable payload from fun while it is collecting data from main thread?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should organize your program to model the data-flow from the sensor to the database. So, you would have a single timer that calls the sampling method at the polling rate. Pass the result of the sampling method to a buffering method. Fill the buffer until the buffering period has elapsed. Finally, post the buffer, each time it fills up.

```
import random
import time

def generate_samples():
    while True:
        input('Press ENTER to simulate next sample...')
        yield random.random()

def period_elapsed(period_start, period_duration):
    return period_start + period_duration < time.time()

def collect_buffers(samples, buffer_period):
    buffer_time = time.time()
    buffer_samples = []
    for sample in samples:
        buffer_samples.append(sample)
        if period_elapsed(buffer_time, buffer_period):
            yield buffer_samples
            buffer_samples = []
            buffer_time = time.time()

def post_buffers(buffers, url):
    for b in buffers:
        requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(buffer))

post_buffers(collect_buffers(generate_samples(), 300), 'http://localhost:3000')
```

Comment: Thanks, I still cannot see how to solve the issue of posting the buffer while it is populating data simultaneously. Another note, the sampling rate is not consitant, it depends on the availablitiy of the sensed objects.

Comment: You'll have to craft the condition for posting the buffer based on your needs. I added sample code to illustrate one way of implementing the pipeline from sample generation to posting buffers.